# What is the functional derivative of an integral with d'Alembertian Operator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I want to take the functional derivative of an integral with a d'Alembertian Operator:

$$ \frac{\delta }{\delta F(x)} \int d^4y\,G(x) \partial_\mu \partial^\mu F(y) $$

I believe this is related to the product rule (or integration by parts) and tried the following:

$$ \partial_\mu \partial^\mu (F\cdot G)
 =\partial_\mu \left( F \partial^\mu  G + G \partial^\mu  F \right )= 2 \partial_\mu G\, \partial^\mu  F  +F\partial_\mu \partial^\mu G +G\partial_\mu \partial^\mu F $$
which implies:
$$ \int d^4y\, G\,\partial_\mu  \partial^\mu F 
 = \int d^4y\, \partial_\mu \partial^\mu (F\cdot G)
 - 2\int d^4y\,  \partial_\mu F \,\partial^\mu  G  -\int d^4y\,F\, \partial_\mu \partial^\mu G $$
And although I know that:

$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta F(x)} \int d^4y\,F(y)h(y) = h(x) $$
and
$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta F(x)} \int d^4y \partial_\mu F(y)V(y)^\mu = - \partial_\mu V^\mu(x)  $$
which can help me with the second term.

I still don't know what to make of the term:
$$ \int d^4y\, \partial_\mu \partial^\mu (F\cdot G) $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the identity
$$
G \left(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu F\right) = \partial_\mu \left( G \partial^\mu F\right) - \partial^\mu \left( \left(\partial_\mu G\right) F\right) + \left(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu G\right) F \, . \quad (*)
$$
Then you have
$$
\int \text{d}^4x \, G \left(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu F\right) = \int \text{d}^4x \,  \left(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu G\right) F \, , 
$$
because the first two terms on the right-hand side of (*) are surface terms that do not contribute to the integral. The functional derivative is then easy
$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta F(x)} \int \text{d}^4x \, G \partial_\mu \partial^\mu F = \partial_\mu \partial^\mu G(x) \, .
$$

Comment: Could you please explain why the surface terms do not contribute to the integral?

Comment: This is an additional assumption that is customary in physics. The idea is that things are going on here, but not at the edge of the universe. Fields are assumed to vanish as $x\rightarrow \infty$.